# How to redirect on tRPC error in SvelteKit?

Tags: typescript, authorization, svelte, sveltekit, trpc.io

I am using `tRPC` with SvelteKit for the first time, and I am stuck trying to validate the user's authentication.

I have the following in `hooks.server.ts`:

```
import { createContext } from '$lib/trpc/context';
import { router } from '$lib/trpc/router';
import type { Handle, HandleServerError } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { createTRPCHandle } from 'trpc-sveltekit';

import { getHTTPStatusCodeFromError } from '@trpc/server/http';

const trpcHandleError = ({ type, path, error }) => {
    console.error(`Encountered error while trying to process ${type} @ ${path}:`, error);
    const httpStatus = getHTTPStatusCodeFromError(error);

    if (httpStatus === 401) {
        // How do I redirect here??
    } else if (httpStatus == 403) {
        // Throw a 404
    }
}

export const handle: Handle = createTRPCHandle({ router, createContext, onError: trpcHandleError });

export const handleError: HandleServerError = ({ error, event }) => {
    // ...or here?
}
```

My question is: How do I redirect the user within the `trpcHandleError` to `/login` if the `error.code` is `UNAUTHORIZED`?

I've tried simply `throw redirect(307, '/login');` but it was just ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onError` is a hook that gets notified when error occurs, but gives you no control over the response result.

Instead, you can provide a `responseMeta` function param to `createTRPCHandle({ responseMeta })`. This function is supposed to return a meta object that has `{ status, headers }` keys, which affects the final response ([source code](https://github.com/trpc/trpc/blob/0f28fe212a96a6aabe795b50b0f55f66bb94531e/packages/server/src/http/resolveHTTPResponse.ts#L91-L100)).

It has following function signature:

```js
const { status, headers } = responseMeta({
  ctx,
  paths,
  type,
  data: Array<{ error: ... } | { result: { data: ... } }>,
});
```

You can read the `params.data` array, and filter out items that have `error` key to handle them. To achieve the same effect of `redirect(307, '/login')`, you need to return a meta object of shape:

```
{ status: 307, headers: { Location: "/login" } }
```

Comment: I implemented a preliminary version of this, but how would one go about adding a redirect back to the original URL after re-authing?

Comment: @DavidLee I believe you can respond with `{ status: 307, headers: { Location: "/login?redirect_url=..." } }`, and handle the redirection in `/login` route.